# I need log data for the detected objects in Python OpenCV

Tags: python, logging

How can I log the data from detecting an object or of face in Python OpenCV? I have not been able to find a way to do it successfully as of yet.

Here is code that I added:

```
label = "{}: {:.2f}%".format(CLASSES[idx], confidence * 100)

cv2.rectangle(frame, (startX, startY), (endX, endY), COLORS[idx], 2)

y = startY - 15 if startY - 15 > 15 else startY + 15
cv2.putText(frame, label, (startX, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, COLORS[idx], 2)

#print (label + "\n")
print(label)
```

Now when I run this I do see the label of the category detected, but I need to get this out to a log file.

Comment: What is the specific issue you’re encountering? Asking for libraries etc. is explicitly off-topic.

Comment: Are you suggesting that searching the internet for "python logging" yields no useful information?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The easiest solution for logging is to use [pythons module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html). A very basic example:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename="log.txt", level=logging.INFO)
logging.info("this will be written to log.txt")
```